# rendering of tikzcd code to get an image file

Tags: texstudio, kile

I have Kile and Texstudio in my computer.

For some reason, I want to save commutative diagrams as image files.

There is http://presheaf.com/ that compiles xymatrix codes and gives an image file.

I am not aware of anything that runs tikzcd code and gives an image file.

There is https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/ that gives tikzcd code but do not give image.

Is there any way to run tikzcd code in kile/Texstudio and get an image file? Not the full file as image file but can I be able to save diagram in pdf output as an image?

Taking a screen shot in pdf output and cropping is not an option for me.

I do not know very much about these installations and all. Please write a detailed answer.

EDIT : It seems it was not clear what I was asking. I just want to get an image file from my tikzcd code. Even if it is a website just like presheaf.com you write a xypic code, you get an image file I am ok with it if it takes tikzcd code to give an image. I have no preference for format of image file svg png anything is ok.

Comment: I am ok with any pages online also that renders tikz code and give me an image file.. But asking that may be off topic here..

Comment: I'd just make a standalone doc for each, using the `standalone` class, then each generated PDF is a cropped stand alone image

Comment: @daleif I am not aware of what standalone doc is... and i dont understand what is "then each generated PDF is a cropped stand alone image"

Comment: It is a documentclass just like `article`, just very good for compiling images to just the images.

Comment: @daleif can you please make it as an answer adding some more details..

Comment: You are dealing with (La)TeX, meaning you get a pdf file (or dvi). A vector format. You can convert the resulting pdf to a raster format like jpg or png.  But really, the answers below are the state of the art LaTeX solutions.

Comment: @Johannes_B I dont speak good english.. can you tell me in simple words what do you mean by " But really, the answers below are the state of the art LaTeX solutions."

Comment: Below are the LaTeX solutions. It seems like you are looking for something different, like MathJax, which can render your LaTeX-like equation as math on a web page.

Comment: @Johannes_B Not necessarily that, but it is also helpful.... Are you saying below answers gives me an image file when I compile tex in Kile/Tex studio

Comment: A cropped pdf file the size of the equation. You can use that or convert to png.

Comment: answer by Bernard gives cropped pdf file the size of the equation. I then have to convert from Internet. Can it be done from kile/Tex studio only? @Johannes_B I do not understand what Tom's answer is saying..

Comment: Toms answer does the same (in the background) as bernards answer. You can tell the standalone class to do the converion in the background using an extra tool. Have a look at the manual.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your commutative diagrams with the `standalone` class and include the resulting .pdf in another file with `\includegraphicx{mycd}`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{φ} \arrow[swap]{d}{\varrho_f} & B \arrow{d}{\varrho_g} \\%
A_f \arrow{r}{\varphi_f}& B_g
\end{tikzcd} 

\end{document}
```

Resulting in (slightly zoomed)– note how the .pdf is cropped :

[image]

Demo on how to use it: the `previous.pdf` being saved as `cdaspdf.pdf` and being automatically cropped by the `standalone` class, the following code incorporates the diagram in another .pdf with  this example-code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\lipsum[10]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics{cdaspdf}
\end{center}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

Note that as the diagram is incorporated as a vector image, it can be zoomed without any problem.

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what does it mean to say "include the resulting .pdf in another file with \includegraphicx{mycd}"

Comment: I did not understand what you said but I converted pdf to image and then added in my question.. please let me know if this is not what you mean to say and if anything better can be done

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I've added a demo using the resulting pdf  *directly* in another file (not converted to .png or .jpeg), so that it can be zoomed *ad libitum*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. it was not for adding in another file.. I can just add the code itself, why round I create another file and then add as include graphics? I wanted to get a image file to add in a website..

Comment: It seeems I misunderstood what you really wanted. There remains that you might want to convert the cropped diagram to `svg` to have it zoomable?

Comment: I just want to get an image file... Just like http://presheaf.com/ you write a xypic code, you get an image file... i have no preference for format of image file svg png anything is ok

Answer (score 3):

You can try externalizing the tikz graphics using this code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetexternalprefix{ext-tikz/} % files will be stored as a pdf here
```

You can set a better filename by appending this:

```
\newcommand{\includetikz}[1]{%
    \tikzsetnextfilename{#1}%
    \input{#1.tex}%
}
```

Comment: I do not understand (very new to these)... can you tell me step by step what to do.. apologies.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an answer native to TeXstudio and making use of its inline preview functionality. *No need* for external documents, post-processing with scripts, nor modifying of your existing preamble.

Modifying @Bernard's example code to something you would typically have in a normal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

% Some other stuff here in your document...

\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow{r}{\phi} \arrow[swap]{d}{\varrho_f} & B \arrow{d}{\varrho_g} \\%
    A_f \arrow{r}{\varphi_f}& B_g
\end{tikzcd} 

% Some other stuff here in your document...

\end{document}
```

Highlight the `tikzcd` environment, right click and select `Preview selection / Parenthesis` in the dropdown menu.
A resulting preview image will be generated, which you can then right-click on to save as a `.jpg`/`.png` file.

[image]